# Catch print screen key code

Tags: android, keycode, printscreen

How I can catch the "print screen" key code? (volume up + volume down, volume down + app_switch, ...) so I can hide view, which is triggered by the volume down button?

I'm trying `KEYCODE_SYSQR`, but it will not capture the printscreen shortcut...

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_SYSRQ

Probably does not help detecting when the user took a print screen because I can not hide the view after...

Thanks

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Use `FLAG_SECURE` to prevent your activity from being captured in a screenshot.

Comment: I know about this, but this is not solution. :-)